# Trying to connect to XMPP server using android Smack client library throws CertPathValidatorException

Tags: android, certificate, xmpp, anchor, smack

This is my piece of code:

```
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.Builder connectionBuilder = 
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder();

    connectionBuilder
            .setHost(MY_HOST)
            .setServiceName(MY_SERVICE_NAME)
            .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
            .setDebuggerEnabled(true);


    XMPPTCPConnection connection = new         XMPPTCPConnection(connectionBuilder.build());
    connection.connect();
```

When running, I get this exception:

```
W/System.err: org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

Does anyone have any fast solution to overcome this issue? I am not interested in deep understanding of the SSL protocol etc. I also don't care about security on this stage of my project.

I also want to mention that I succeeded connecting to the server using Swift application, so the issue is probably not on the server side. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

```
    // Create a connection to the jabber.org server.
    // Create the configuration for this new connection
    InetAddress addr = null;
    try {
        addr = InetAddress.getByName("192.***.**.**");
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    HostnameVerifier verifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return false;
        }
    };
    DomainBareJid serviceName = null;
    try {
        serviceName = JidCreate.domainBareFrom("localhost");
    } catch (XmppStringprepException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration config = 

XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                .setUsernameAndPassword(USER_CURRENT_USER, "password")
                .setPort(5222)
                .setSecurityMode(ConnectionConfiguration.SecurityMode.disabled)
                .setXmppDomain(serviceName)
                .setHostnameVerifier(verifier)
                .setHostAddress(addr)
                .setDebuggerEnabled(true)
                .build();

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);
        try {
            connection.connect();
        } catch (SmackException | IOException | InterruptedException | XMPPException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

try this and let me know if it worked for you..

Answer (score 0):

chek out this link ..[XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration](http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.jivesoftware.smack.tcp.XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help. These are just common examples which don't show how to solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the certificate of the server you are trying to reach to your JDK trust store, or disable the verification of hostname like shown above.